# The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type fetcher

Tags: android, jsoup

Iam trying to use the jsoup to return string from a web site and view the string in textview but i got this error

The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type fetcher

my code is :

```
public class Second extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_second, menu);
    return true;
}

public void Iqama (View view) throws IOException
{
    //Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
    new fetcher().execute();
}
```

}

class fetcher extends AsyncTask{
    String myString = null;

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) { 
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ismmusalla.org/").get();
            Elements divs = doc.select("div#title1");


                for (Element div : divs) {
                    myString=myString+" " +div.text();
                      }



        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

}

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result)
 {
     TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     textview.setText(myString);

 }
```

}

could you please help me ????

Comment: did you try the below?

Comment: long time no reply. have you tried the below? does it work for you??

Comment: finally you accepted the answer after a long time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can findViewById of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.

Declare textview as a class variable.

In onCreate()

```
    textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Make your asynctask inner class of your activity class.

```
public class Second extends Activity {

TextView textview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    new fetcher().execute();    
}


 class fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
 String myString = null;
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) { 
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ismmusalla.org/").get();
            Elements divs = doc.select("div#title1");
                for (Element div : divs) {
                    myString=myString+" " +div.text();
                      }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(void result)
 {
     textview.setText(myString);

 }
}
}
```